# HTML/CSS Image grid

Tags: html, css, image

I am a back-end developer and I need a little help with some HTML/CSS to replace one large image with multiple small images. The smaller images should take up the exact same area as the larger image. Here's the HTML I have now for the larger image:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="myimage.jpg" width= "300" height="190" border="0">
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So the above works perfectly to display my large image. Now I want to replace the img tag with some divs, I think?, and some CSS so that I can place small images by x and y position so that when pieced together occupy the same 300x190 as the large image.

For example if I assume that the top left is 0, 0 and x increases as I go to the right and y increases as I go down and I'm placing my images using the x,y of the upper left hand corner. Then I could take two images that are both 150x190 and place the first at 0,0 and the second as 150,0.

What is the best HTML/CSS for this?

Edit: I need to handle this in an arbitrary sense. So there couple be a bunch of small images that all have their own x,y as opposed to the simple example above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `absolute` inside `relative` positioning.

**See:** http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/zwwwt/

The inner `div`s could just as easily be `img`s.

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <div style="top: 0; left: 0; width: 100px; height: 50px"></div>
    <div style="top: 0; left: 100px; width: 200px; height: 50px"></div>
    <div style="top: 50px; left: 0; width: 150px; height: 150px"></div>
    <div style="top: 50px; left: 150px; width: 150px; height: 150px"></div>
</div>

.imageContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red
}
.imageContainer div {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    outline: 1px dashed #000
}
```

Comment: this is looking like what i need. thank you. ill get back to you with more questions or a green check

Answer (score 5):

If your already using a table for this, why not just add more rows/columns to create your 2x2 grid and enter each image in there.  It would be the fastest solution.

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="myimage1.jpg" width= "150"  border="0"></td>
    <td><img src="myimage2.jpg" width= "150"  border="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="myimage3.jpg" width= "150"  border="0"></td>
    <td><img src="myimage4.jpg" width= "150"  border="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: because that was just a simple example. it needs to be able to handle any number of images and each could have any x,y. it could be 20 smaller images that are more intricately placed.

Comment: This is still a fine way to do it, you'd loop through to produce the table in your PHP.

Comment: I don't think so. it's not always going to be in nice rows and columns. for example the first image might be 10x10 and x=0, y=0. then the next image might be 40x35 and x = 10, y=0. it's basically arbitrary rectangular puzzle pieces and I have the x and y vales. see what i mean.